# WiFi does not work properly on my phone only

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, connection-issues, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z

This problem occured randomly. I have this problem for a week now.

My phone does not connect to the router, although it shows it in the list. If I get very close to the router (max. 2-3 meters) it does work.

I have tried setting the router to 5 or 2.4Ghz and tried different channels. The router does not show any problems. Also deleting the WiFi profile on the phone and re-adding it normally or via WPS does not help. I even installed another ROM on the phone (was on a 5.1.1 ROM, changed to stock one).

The connection works fine on at least 10 other devices (no, they are not connected at the same time, that's not the problem ^^)

Phone: Sony Xperia Z, newest firmware (Android 5.0.2)
Router: Fritz!Box 7490, newest firmware (113.06.30)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue for me. To zero on it, can you measure the wifi signal strength from this and another device with both next to each other? If your Sony Xperia Z reports a lower signal strength than other, it could be a hardware issue.  You can also try the `*#*#4636#*#*` key sequence as well.

Comment: @Narayanan I don't think this is a hardware issue. Although my model is pretty old, the device is only some weeks old. I have an insurance for the phone and got the new one ~6 weeks ago... I had to be pretty unlucky for this. My notebook has 4/5 bars when my phone disconnects

Comment: I agree with @Narayanan but have you tested the signal while its plugged in/full battery and turning off Bluetooth & mobile data?

Comment: @XLR8 It kinda works. The signal strength is higher. 3/4 bars. But if I click on it and then on "connect" it just does nothing. Sometimes (rarely) I get an authentication error.

Comment: @kaesaecracker It has to be a hardware problem/power problem, I would suggest you Google your phones make with your problem and if you don't find anything then just take it to a phone repair shop/get a new phone